# How can I set up USPS Shipping to have options given only if a certain amount of items are being checked out?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, magento2.3, usps

How can I set up **`USPS` Shipping** to have options given only if a certain amount of items are being **checked out**?

I'm using `USPS` for shipping and I want it to use a small flat rate box if there are lets say 5 items in the `cart`. Then, if there are more than 5 it would only give the option of `medium flat rate box`. Then finally, more than 10 a large flat rate box. How could I set the `USPS` shipping on magento to do this?

I'm on base `Magento 2.3`